# Apache: resources not loaded after a redirect with proxypass

Tags: apache-2.2, proxy, virtualhost, reverse-proxy, proxypass

**Configuration:**

- One virtual machine with Docked installed (10.10.10.68)

  - One Docker container for myapp with apache installed (10.10.10.68:8080)
  - A second docker container with superset installed (10.10.10.68:8088)

**Problem:**

I'm trying to create a redirect of all incoming requests comes to first container on /superset route to second container where superset is installed.

In url, the redirect seems working well, the web page is not displayed correctly because on superset container, it's impossible to access to resources, assets..

**Apache config:**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin me@mydomain.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/myapp/current/public

  ProxyPass /superset/ http://10.10.10.68:8088/

  <Location /superset/>
        ProxyPassReverse /
        ProxyHTMLEnable On
        ProxyHTMLURLMap http://10.10.10.68:8088/ /superset/
        ProxyHTMLURLMap / /superset/
  </Location>

  <Directory /var/www/myapp/current/public/>
      Options +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
      AllowOverride All
      Require all granted
  </Directory>

  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Error:

[image]

Comment: I don't know what the superset app is, but many applications do not do well having their "context" or root route changed (e.g. by having the /superset/ application served under /). There are configuration directives and modules to help you attempt to do so, but most of the time it doesn't work. You may want to consider having the proxy container redirect requests to / to the /superset/ route, and then just pass /superset/ onto the upstream container.

Comment: What is the proxy container in my env?

Comment: The apache container is the proxy- it is to proxy requests "back", or "upstream", to the superset container. Does that make sense?

Comment: You say that i may consider to redirect requests to / to the superset route. I don't well understand what i'hve to do. is my apache configuration file is correct on apache container ?

Comment: Have a look at the destination Apache logfiles, you should have details on what triggered the 404s.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood, you want all requests for http://container1/superset to be forwarded to http://container2:8088

Correct?

Would a simple:

```
  ProxyPass /superset http://10.10.10.68:8088/
  ProxyPassReverse /superset http://10.10.10.68:8088/
```

instead of:

```
  ProxyPass /superset/ http://10.10.10.68:8088/

  <Location /superset/>
        ProxyPassReverse /
        ProxyHTMLEnable On
        ProxyHTMLURLMap http://10.10.10.68:8088/ /superset/
        ProxyHTMLURLMap / /superset/
  </Location>
```

work?

See: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html -> "Basic Examples"

Comment: Yes it's correct. But with the 2 lines that you propose to put in my configuration, it doesn't work because there is an immediate redirection to /superset/welcome which is not taken into account with your proposed rule.

Comment: Can you update the question with what happens? The simple configuration above should proxy all requests from container1 to container2, including redirects to sub-paths under /superset/ that get issued by the application on container2. One thing that may be happening is container2 is issuing a redirect with a bad domain name. If this is the case, the solution is probably to add a ProxyPreserveHost On directive to the above simple configuration.